# Getting the button text in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have created a custom locator to find an element with the `ng-click` method used. I have used it to get a reference to a button in my DOM.

```
this.button = element(by.ngClick('login()'));
```

i want to get the text that is on the button from the reference. For example if the button has "Click to Login" as the text, how can i extract that from the `button` reference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call [`getText()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) on the element selector, but keep in mind it returns a promise. The promise could be fed to `expect` though, it would resolve it and perform the comparision:

```
expect(this.button.getText()).toBe('Click to Login');
```

If you need to use the text for anything else in your code you'll have to resolve the promise yourself:

```
this.button.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```